# Minimizing the cost of using the Hiring Problem

Tags: algorithm

I have gone through one of the books of algorithm and have found a problem named Hiring Problem.  Here is the situation:

I have to conduct an interview for hiring candidates for my company.
I am not personally able to conduct the interview, as I have failed to do so. So I have hired an employment agency to help with hiring the candidate. Each day the agency will send me a candidate from among n candidates.  Algorithm for this will be:

```
**Algo Hiring Candidate(n)**  
best=0 // The candidate with the least quality  
for i=1 to n  
If the candidate is better than the best valued candidate we should hire him  
Best=candidate[i]  
return i;
```

But here, the interview cost will be always calculated as we have to take the interview of each candidate. So we have to concentrate on how to minimize the hiring cost.

**Total cost will be O(interview cost and hiring cost)**

I have gone through many observations, such as the agency will send the candidate randomly and in the **worst case** we have to hire all the candidates, then the hiring cost will be higher as each candidate came in an order of increasing quality.

But practically this is not possible, as it is never possible that all the candidates will come always in increasing order. They should come in a random order.

I have taken many observations but I am really not able to minimize the hiring cost. Can someone help me out through this problem.

Comment: Looks like a fun problem... is this for a class?

Comment: No sir...I have asked this so that I can improve my thinking ability.

Comment: The difference between your question and the secretary problem amelvin mentions comes in the form of _costs_.  I'm having trouble understanding what the costs are, however.  There seems to be a constant cost for each interview - i assume the hiring cost is just the sum of all interview costs?  The problem is that you can't optimize hiring cost and candidate quality at the same time without some quantified trade off between them.

Comment: regarding the "worst case" you mention, I don't understand how you would hire more than one person.  I thought the problem was to pick a _single candidate_ to hire.  do you mean that the worst case would be having to _interview_ all the candidates?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is an example of the [Secretary Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

Comment: Yup,but am not able to actually minimize the hiring cost.

Comment: That's my thought, too. So if I'm not mistaken, he should see 1/e of the candidates, then choose the best after that, right?

Comment: I can't understand what you wanna say.

Comment: You cannot choose before 1/e, or it would not be optimal.

Comment: That what I want to find.The hiring cost should be optimal.Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: This is a famous Dynamic Programming problem (it is computer science, not just programming though). "The aim is to maximize the probability of choosing the candidate of greatest rank". See [here](http://www.math.kth.se/optsyst/utbildning/kurser/SF2862/introtext.text).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is indeed (a variant of) the hiring problem, which itself is a multi-objective version of the [secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

In the latter, one has a bunch of n candidates arriving in some arbitrary order of quality, and has to take an instant decision (accept the candidate or reject without any second chance). As one sees more and more candidates, one gets a better picture of the overall quality of candidates, but the odds are increasing that the best ones belong to the past (Actually, this problem should be called the "Dating game" or the "Picky Single" if you ask me...). The goal is then to find a strategy which maximizes the probability of getting the best one. This goal can be achieved by looking at n/e out of the n candidates, and then pick the next candidate whose quality exceeds that of the n/e "training set" (first candidates).

Slightly contrasting, the hiring problem aims at selecting many good candidates. As described nicely in the introduction (page 3) of [Dr Ahmed Mohamed Helmi Mohamed Elsadek's PhD manuscript](http://hdl.handle.net/10803/117453), there are two contradictory objectives underlying the hiring problem:

1. Optimize the quality of hired candidates
2. Maximize the number of hired candidates

Note that if only 1. is considered, then the best strategy is very likely the same as for the secretary problem. If only 2. is considered, then simply accept everyone without worrying about their skills. When both are taken into account, one has to merge these two objectives into some sort of optimal tradeoffs, and there is more than one optimal strategy. The above-mentioned thesis has a bunch of nicely explained strategies (cf Preater's “better than-average rule, Krieger, Pollak and Samuel-Cahn's “p-percentile rules”...).

Now, your problem seems slightly different (one pays to see a candidate, and one pays to hire her/him), but I believe that reading the thesis introduction would help you formalize which, of the possible tradeoffs (between number of retained candidates, quality of retained candidates and number of interview), seems best as an objective function and, in turn, which of the strategies seems the most promising.

Comment: After reading the solution to this problem...life does not seem to be fair anymore. I suspect that this problem is not used in practice when hiring people but it is rather used as a model for other decision making problems. But just the idea to reject the first n/e people...is unfair!

Answer (score -1):

Minimizing the cost of using the Hiring Problem involves streamlining the hiring process to reduce time and resources expended. Employ strategies like targeted job postings, efficient screening methods, and structured interviews to find the right candidates swiftly. Additionally, leveraging technology for resume parsing and applicant tracking can enhance efficiency. Silver people, with their experience and expertise, can contribute by providing valuable insights into refining job descriptions, assessing candidate fit, and optimizing the selection criteria, ultimately leading to cost reduction and improved hiring outcome